# How to split the header of an image?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have designed a website which users upload some images and I store them in a folder.but anyone else can access the uploaded file via URL.
However I want to split the header of Uploaded images and insert the header in the database and store the rest of file in the folders.
How can I split the header of image?
If I convert the image to the array of binary how to distinguish the header part?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to break-off the exif data and store the rest?

Comment: why would you want to do that ? for security ?

Comment: that is security by obscurity... better solve that with correct permissions...

Comment: Yes you are right. But one of my colleagues is a php programmer an use this method and it works but I don't know how to do it. How can I do it in ASP.net?

Comment: @RaymondMorphy: You're better off storing the images in a directory, then using a "Getter" script. e.g. `readImage.php?image=unique_image_key` which would spin up the image from your secured directory. (Then use the database to store the image keys)

Comment: But if some one find the folder can see the upload files via url. isn't it?

Comment: @RaymondMorphy: You would setup security on the uploads directory to disallow all viewing, then use the getter to read the directory and output it. (using PHP as a references, the getter would be something like `<?php header('Content-Type: image/jpg'); readfile('uploads/uploadedImage.jpg');` ) (C# of course would be a bit different and would need to write the bytes manually)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that another way . First Encode the Bitmap to base64 and store it at an XML File ,keep XML Files if you want ordered by an ID and store within the XML 2 Items Value and BitmapString .Than from XML you can convert from Base64 to an Bitmap .

```
            //Convert Image to Base64
            Bitmap myBmp = new Bitmap(dialog.FileName);
            MemoryStream theStream = new MemoryStream();
            myBmp.Save(theStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            String base64Containter = Convert.ToBase64String(theStream.ToArray());
            //Write String and Image ID to XML
```

Load image from XML assuming that you already identified the Item into XML:

```
            TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
            char[] theBytes = base64Containter.ToArray();
            Bitmap bitmap1 = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(Convert.FromBase64CharArray(theBytes, 0, theBytes.Length));
            this.pictureBox1.Image = bitmap1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of an image handler to retrieve the image from the db instead of splitting the image,

check [this link](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5223/using-ashx-files-to-retrieve-db-images/) which explains how to create an use an image handler

Comment: But I don't want to store all  of the image in database. because the database will be huge in long time. I just wanna insert the header part